# How to get all unique elements in for an array of array but keep max count of duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The question doesn't make much sense but not sure how to word it without an example. If someone can word it better, feel free to edit it.

Let's say I have an array of arrays such as this:

```
[ ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], [], ['d', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'e'] ]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
 ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Not sure if there is an easy way to do this in javascript/jquery/underscore. One way I could think of is to look through each of these arrays and count up the number of times each element shows up and keep track of the maximum amount of times it shows up. Then I can recreate it. But that seems pretty slow considering that my arrays can be very large.

Comment: Please elaborate, it's really unclear how you're getting to the desired output.  What are the criteria?

Comment: I want to get an array of all the unique elements from all the arrays. But if one of those array have duplicates of the same element, I want the outcome to have that same amount of element as well.

Comment: You mean something like this {a:2,b:3,c:1,d:1, e:1}?

Comment: I guess that would work as well since I can use that to recreate the desired array

Comment: The MDN docs for the `reduce` method has an example exactly for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce ...you could then `sort` the array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: What are you trying to do is to create an array that contains the highest occurrences for each value from the input?

Comment: yes @razvan. Thank you for wording it better than I can.

Comment: Why are there only 3 `b`'s in your desired result array instead of 4?

Comment: @MikeBrant he only want the highest occurrence in one of the child arrays, not the total number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Loop over each inner array and count the values
- Store each value and its count (if higher than current count) in a counter variable
- In the end, convert the value and counts into an array

Following code shows a rough outline of the process. Remember to replace `.forEach` and `for..in` with appropriate code:

```
var input = [['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], [], ['d', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'e']],
    inputCount = {};
input.forEach(function(inner) {
    var innerCount = {};
    inner.forEach(function(value) {
        innerCount[value] = innerCount[value] ? innerCount[value] + 1 : 1;
    });
    var value;
    for (value in innerCount) {
        inputCount[value] = inputCount[value] ? Math.max(inputCount[value], innerCount[value]) : innerCount[value];
    }
});
console.log(inputCount);
// Object {a: 2, b: 3, c: 1, d: 1, e: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

After messing around, I found a solution but not sure if I like it enough to use. I would probably use it if I can't think of another one.

I would use underscorejs countBy to get the count of all the elements.

```
var array = [ ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], [], ['d', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'e'] ];

var count = _.map(array, function(inner) {
  return _.countBy(inner, function(element) {
    return element;
  });
});

var total = {};
_.each(_.uniq(_.flatten(array)), function(element) {
  var max = _.max(count, function(countedElement) {
    return countedElement[element];
  });

  total[element] = max[element];
});

console.log(total); // {a: 2, b: 3, c: 1, d: 1, e: 1}
```

Then I would recreate the array with that total.

Comment: Oh, I was the person asking the question and stated if there was an underscorejs solution for this. Not sure what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution but it should describe you the process:

```
var big = [ ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], [], ['d', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'e'] ];

function map(arr){
    var map = {}
    for (var i=arr.length-1; i>-1; i--){
        if(arr[i] in map) map[arr[i]]++;
        else map[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
    return map;
}

function reduce(matrix){
    var arrMap = {};
    for (var i=matrix.length-1; i>-1; i--){
        var arrRes = map(matrix[i]);
        for (var key in arrRes){
            if( !arrMap[key] || arrMap[key] < arrRes[key])
                arrMap[key] = arrRes[key];
        }
    }
    return arrMap;
}

function calc(matrix){
    var res = [],
      arrMap = reduce(matrix);

    for (var key in arrMap){
        while(arrMap[key] > 0 ){
            res.push(key);
            arrMap[key]--;            
        }
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(calc(big));
// Array [ "e", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "d", "c" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of simple nested loop approach:

```
var input = [ ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], [], ['d', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'e'] ];

var countMap = {};
// iterate outer array
for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
    // iterate inner array
    for (j=0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
        // increment map counter
        var value = input[i][j];
        if (countMap[input[i][j]] === undefined) {
            countMap[value] = 1;
        } else {
            countMap[value]++;
        }
    }
}
console.log(countMap); // output such as {'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':1, 'd':1, 'e':1}
```